# Magento 2: Custom Module's Frontend Controller not calling layout

Tags: magento2, layout, frontend

Below is URL to access

{site url}/magento2/module/mymodule/new

**{folder path}\magento2\app\code\Custom\Module\Controller\MyModule\NewAction.php**

```
namespace Custom\Module\Controller\MyModule;

class NewAction extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface
 */
protected $_cacheTypeList;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\StateInterface
 */
protected $_cacheState;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool
 */
protected $_cacheFrontendPool;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
 */
protected $resultPageFactory;

/**
 * @param Action\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\StateInterface $cacheState
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool $cacheFrontendPool
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
 */
public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList, \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\StateInterface $cacheState, \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool $cacheFrontendPool, \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_cacheTypeList = $cacheTypeList;
    $this->_cacheState = $cacheState;
    $this->_cacheFrontendPool = $cacheFrontendPool;
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
}

/**
 * Flush cache storage
 *
 */
public function execute() {

    $this->_view->loadLayout();
    $this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
    $this->_view->getPage()->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('Test Post'));
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

    return $resultPage;
}
```

}

**{folder path}\magento2\app\code\Custom\Module\view\frontend\layout\module_mymodule_new.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom_module_post_form"
                   template="Custom_Module::index.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

When u run URL on my WAMP it shows blank page. It's not calling layout file from controller.

Comment: In your extension file routes.xml exist or not ?

Comment: Yes it exists. Because i already created home page for   {site url}/magento2/module/ & i'm able to access that page

Comment: Print error and check issue.

Comment: Add layout column `layout="1column"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add layout column `layout="1column"`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom_module_post_form"
                   template="Custom_Module::index.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your controller execute

```
public function execute()
{
    $resultPageFactory = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

    // Add page title
    $resultPageFactory->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('Test'));
    return $resultPageFactory;
}
```

Comment: It's Already Showing Page Title

Comment: got only blank page? check the httpd error log and post your full controller code may be it is useful to figure out what was the issues.

Comment: Yes. only Blank Page. Added Full Code of Controller in Question

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below mentioned site. http://inchoo.net/magento-2/how-to-create-a-basic-module-in-magento-2/ . In this site use for "**How to create a basic module in Magento 2**"

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="1column">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Inchoo\Helloworld\Block\Helloworld" name="helloworld" template="helloworld.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```